# Moving row based on Input value in inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

I need some assitance. What I'm trying to do is to move a row based on the user input in the inputbox. However I received an Invalid Qualifier error. Do help me, thanks! The error highlighted is `lSource` row.

```
Sub MoveRow()

       Dim lDestRow   As Long
       Dim lSourceRow As String
       Dim zMsg       As String

       lSourceRow = InputBox("Please Enter the row you want to move")
       zMsg = "Move Row " & Format(lSourceRow.Row) & " to Row?" & _
              vbCrLf & "Enter 0 to Exit"

       lDestRow = InputBox(zMsg, "Move Entire Row", 0)
       If lDestRow <> 0 And lDestRow <> lSourceRow Then

         ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
         Selection.Cut
         Rows(lDestRow).Select
         Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

       Else

         If lDestRow <> 0 Then

           MsgBox "Source Row and Destination Row" & vbCrLf & _
                  "are the same -NO Action Taken-", _
                  vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
                  "Invalid Row Move Request"

         End If

       End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `LSourceRow` is a string not a range so `LSourceRow.Row` will give out the qualifier error.

Comment: Oh. so i have to declare lsourcerow as a range? Is that how it works? Sorry i am new to VBA

Comment: Ah no, since you are not actually passing a range object to it. Rather, you shouldn't use `.Row` since I believe the user already entered the row number right? And again, `.Row` is a Range object Property.

Comment: i hope it's not asking for too much but i tried it and it didnt work. Could you assist me with the codes?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to achieve. But you can give this a try.

```
With ActiveSheet 'Replace to suit - e.g. Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lSourceRow As Long
    Dim lDestRow As Long
    Dim zMsg As String

    lSourceRow = InputBox("Please Enter the row you want to move.")
    zMsg = "Move Row " & Format(lSourceRow) & " to what Row?" & _
          vbCrLf & "Enter 0 to Exit"

    lDestRow = InputBox(zMsg, "Move Entire Row", 0)

    If lDestRow <> 0 And lSourceRow <> 0 Then
        If lDestRow <> lSourceRow Then
            .Rows(lSourceRow).Cut
            .Rows(lDestRow + IIf(lDestRow = 1, 0, 1)).Insert xlDown
        Else
            MsgBox "Source Row and Destination Row" & vbCrLf & _
                "are the same -NO Action Taken-", _
                vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
                "Invalid Row Move Request."
        End If
    End If
End With
```

This is the simplest form. What you want done must include a lot of test on the input.
Like testing if it is not negative, not a string or decimal or if the user presses **Cancel** or **Close**.
This is just something for you to start with. I leave the rest to you. 
This literally move the row to the previous location of the target row. HTH.